# Calculus - Sequence and Function - hard exercise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

EDIT: With your help I have succeed to prove it! Thanks! I also have another question related to this one - written down here.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and let $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable function, let $t \in [a,b]$, and consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1=t & \\ 
x_{n+1}=f(x_n) & \forall n\geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Suppose that there exists a point $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Prove, while using MVT, that if there exists a $0 \le q <1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le q$ for every $x \in [a,b]$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$

-

I don't know how to use MVT here, since I don't know nothing about $\alpha$ and $x_n$, I can't take the interval $[\alpha,x_n]$ or $[x_n,\alpha]$, ($\alpha$ and $x_n$ can be equal).

Any help will be awesome!

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Now I have a $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$:

$$x_0=y ~ ~ , ~ ~ x_{n+1}=cos(x_n), \forall n \ge 0$$

Prove thatt the sequence converge to a limit $0<\alpha<1$.

Any tips?

Thanks again!

Comment: Hint: Using Mean Value Theorem, observe that the sequence at your disposal is a contractive sequence!

Comment: @Brozovic I don't know how to apply MVT...

Comment: @Brozovic This is not how I usually use MVT, can you explain what you did here please? Thanks!

Comment: I meant $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|=|f'(\xi)||x_n-x_{n-1}| \le q|x_n -x_{n-1}|<|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ . Sorry there was a lot of typo in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and applies the interval $[a,b]$ onto itself, the mean value theorem already tells you that there is at least one point in those conditions. The condition on the derivative gives you uniqueness. If there were two distinct $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ in those conditions, then
$$
|\alpha_1-\alpha_2| = |f(\alpha_1)-f(\alpha_2)| \leq q |\alpha_1-\alpha_2|
$$

and so,

$$
(1-q)|\alpha_1-\alpha_2|\leq 0.
$$

since $0< q < 1$ and $|\alpha_1-\alpha_2|\ge 0$, the only possibility is that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.

The convergence of the sequence can now be derived from the inequality
$$
|x_n - \alpha|\leq q|x_{n-1}-\alpha| \leq \cdots \leq q^{n-1}|x_1-\alpha| \leq (b-a) q^{n-1} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
So you are showing that $\alpha$ is unique, which I understand, but what about if $\alpha=x_n$?

Comment: @TheCalc if $x_n=\alpha$ for some $n$, the sequence will be constant after that...

Comment: That is true, but than I can't use MVT for those intervals...

Comment: @TheCalc everything is happening in the interval $[a,b]$. What intervals are you talking about?

Comment: $[\alpha,x_n]$ or $[x_n,\alpha]$

Comment: @TheCalc You can use always $[a,b]$. If fact it is important not to change the interval from iteration to iteration because yoiu want to establish the result to every $x_1 \in [a,b]$. This the standard proof of the fixed point theorem in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks again! I do not understand, if you are working in $[a,b]$, than you should get that since $f$ is differentiable and continuous on $[a,b]$ than there exists a point $a<c<b$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, and not those $\alpha_{1,2}$ that you mentioned.

Comment: @TheCalc The proof does not resume to the MVT... The MVT is only used to establish that for any $x,y \in [a,b]$ it is always true that $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)| |x.y| \leq q |x-y|$.

Comment: Alright I understand this now! So for every $x,y \in [a,b] ~~ s.t ~~ x<y$ we get $|f(y)-f(x)| \le q|y-x|$ - cool! Than you showed the uniqueness of $\alpha$ which I understand too. But how you showed the last inequality? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just note that $$|x_n-\alpha| = |f(x_{n-1})-f(\alpha)| \leq q |x_{n-1}-\alpha|$$
and keep repeating until you reach $|x_1-\alpha|$.

Comment: I see, and I need to check the possibility of $x_n=\alpha$? Thanks again!

Comment: @TheCalc No need to check that specific case... it adds nothing to the conclusions.

Answer (score 3):

Take any two points $x_1, x_2 \in [a,b]$ such that $x_1<x_2$. Using MVT on $[x_1,x_2]$ we get
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq q|x_1-x_2|
\end{equation}
. If there exists another $\beta \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\beta)=\beta$ then $|\alpha-\beta|\leq q |\alpha-\beta|$ which implies such $\alpha$ is unique.
\begin{equation}
|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|\leq q|x_n-x_{n-1}| \leq \cdots\leq q^{n-1}|x_2-x_1|=q^{n-1}|f(t)-t|
\end{equation}
If $n>m$
\begin{align}
|x_{m}-x_n| &\leq |x_{m+1} - x_{m+2}|  + \cdots + |x_{n+1} - x_n |\\
              &\leq  (q^{m} +\cdots +q^ {n-1} )|f (t )- t |\\
              &\leq \frac{q^{m}}{1-q} |f (t )- t |
\end{align}
Since $q<1$, $\{x_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. As $[a,b]$ is complete with respect to $|\cdot|$, there exists $\gamma \in [a,b]$ such that $x_n \rightarrow \gamma$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. By continuity of $f$, $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) =f(\gamma)$ also $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}x_{n+1}= \gamma$. Thus $\gamma=f(\gamma)$. But since $\alpha$ is unique $\alpha=\gamma$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n}= \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain more the second sentence? Thanks!

Comment: There I'm basically showing that $\exists$ a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ which is proved since $ |\alpha-\beta|\leq q |\alpha-\beta|\Rightarrow |\alpha-\beta|=0\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$ for $q<1$. I use this in the last line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If you have extra time to look at my edit, I need to prove another thing, I will very appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By using the MVT you can show:
$$
|f(b) - f(a)| < b-a.
$$
Now, have a look at the Banach fixed point theorem for some inspiration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: I don't know how to apply MVT in this case..

Comment: You mean to get what I showed? You use the statement $|f'(x)| \leq q$ that was given, which applies to all $x\in[a,b]$. If you assume some $c\in[a,b]$ then from the MVT you get:
$$
|f'(c)| \leq q \Rightarrow -q \leq  f'(c) \leq  q \Rightarrow -q \leq \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} \leq q
$$
Now use that $q < 1$.