# Suppose f : R → R is differentiable and there exists a constant C<1 so that |f'(x)| ≤ C for all x ∈ R. Prove that f has a fixed point. Am I correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Sketch proof: If x$_{n+1}$ = f(x$_n$), then by the Mean Value Theorem f(x$_{n+1}$) - f(x$_n$) = (x$_{n+1}$ - x$_n$)f'(c) for some c ∈ ℝ, which becomes x$_{n+2}$ - x$_{n+1}$ = (x$_{n+1}$ - x$_n$)f'(c). This means |(x$_{n+2}$-x$_{n+1}$)/(x$_{n+1}$-x$_n$)| < 1, so |x$_{n+2}$-x$_{n+1}$| < |x$_{n+1}$-x$_n$|. Thus |x$_{n+1}$ - x$_n$| is monotonically decreasing and bounded from below by 0, hence it converges to 0. So f(x$_n$) = x$_{n+1}$ converges to f(x) = x

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Decreasing and bounded below by zero does not imply convergent to zero. take $2/n +3$.

Comment: You have to prove that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, its limit is a fixed point.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah If I said "Suppose |x$_{n+1}$ - x$_n$| converges to some p > 0. Then |f(x$_{n+1}$) - f(x$_n$)|also converges to p, and |f(x$_{n+1}$)-f(x$_n$)| / |x$_{n+1}$ - x$_n$| = f'(c), which becomes p/p = 1 = f'(c), contradicting the fact that |f'(c)| < 1 for all c in R" would that make my proof correct/valid?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Because |f(x$_{n+1}$ - f(x$_n$)| = |x$_{n+2}$ - x$_{n+1}$|

Comment: This should answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089914/calculus-sequence-and-function-hard-exercise/4089994#4089994